# how can I print the amount of memory that each task uses in Android

Tags: android, memory

I save all the tasks in the activity manager
by using this code

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

now, I can get some information from this list like for example the pid of each task etc

but how can I find out how much memory each tasks uses? is it possible to do so from having obtained the above list?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ActovityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getProcessMemoryInfo%28int%5B%5D%29) and iterate the array.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info : activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
            Debug.MemoryInfo[] memInfo = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{info.pid});
            for (Debug.MemoryInfo memoryInfo : memInfo) {
                //
            }
        }
```